# How to restore mysql backup using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to know if it is possible (and preferable how to do it) to restore a mysql backup into the database. Right now I'm doing like this:

```
dump_path = "/tmp/backup.sql"
system "mysql db_name < #{dump_path}"
```

I found out on Stack Overflow a way to do it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
dump_path = "/tmp/backup.sql"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute IO.read(dump_path)
```

The error raised is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COL' at line 8
```

I'd like to achieve interoperability between operating systems, and my current solution would only work on Unix-like systems.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you want to use Rails for this. Database backups are not really a responibity of the application.  Instead use the normal proceedures for backing up and restoring proceedures with the command line and a mysql prompt. Or you can use GUI tools like phpmyadmin. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/using-mysqldump.html

Comment: mysql needs user and password to execute sql files. so try -u root -pyourrottpassword